# Kivy image and DragBehavior

Tags: python, image, drag-and-drop, kivy-language

I am looking at the answer given at :
[Draggable Image in Kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63617496/draggable-image-in-kivy)
Which is kinda what I am looking for.
BUT
trying to run it as is (with the kv file and w/o) I get the:

TypeError: metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases

Because of:

```
class MoveableImage(DragBehavior, Image):
    pass
```

Trying to solve it with metaclass=DragBehavior, will force me to change the order of the params to:

```
class MoveableImage(Image, metaclass=DragBehavior):
    pass
```

And I still get the same metaclass error as before.

Any ideas ?

Eli7

Comment: Hello, Maybe this page can help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276037/resolving-metaclass-conflicts

Comment: Thank you. what did the trick was to import Image from kivy.uix.image instead of PIL Image. It was a good enough solution for me so I did not investigate further.

Comment: glad to hear :) Have a great day